# Table Join on Column Name to Column Value

Tags: mysql

I have seen a number of questions that are similar but I can`t seem to find one that matches what I need to do...

I have the following 2 tables:

Table 1 (ambro_awards_categories):

```
id  cat_name    category
1   cat1        Would most likely know how to fondue an ant
2   cat2        Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter
3   cat3        Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter
4   cat4        Category 4
5   cat5        Category 5
6   cat6        Category 6
7   cat7        Category 7
8   cat8        Category 8
9   cat9        Category 9
```

And table 2(ambro_awards) :

```
id  voter_name          cat1                cat2                cat>>>      date
1   Cavey Charlesworth  Cavey Charlesworth  Cavey Charlesworth  ...         2015-01-18 00:00:00
2   Lynn Wylder         Lynn Wylder         Lynn Wylder         ...         2015-01-18 00:00:00
3   Lynn Wylder         Peter Parker        Batman              ...         2015-01-18 00:00:00
etc
```

What I want to do (and I fully accept there is probably a better way of doing this out there) is to join everything together in 1 big table, joined on the cat1, cat2, etc. So that I can amend the Category names to longer, more descriptive names, without lengthening the 2nd table.

This would mean doing it on the cat_name values of table 1 to the cat1, cat2 column names in Table 2.

The required result would be something like:

```
Would most likely know how to fondue an ant (ie "Category 1")
     name 1
     name 2
     name 3
     name 4... etc

Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter (ie "Category 2")
     name 1
     name 2
     name 3
     name 4... etc

Most likeley to succeed (ie "Category 3")
     name 1
     name 2
     name 3
     name 4... etc
```

That sort of thing...

If it is simple to just add the multiple names to the 1 table, I will do so, but thought that might be a tad wrong... Was hoping to do the above, but then ran into issues...

Pj.

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please also give sample data input and output.

Comment: I suspect I might need a PIVOT but I have no idea how to do one and getting confused trying to understand the resources out there (though it is late currently so might make sense tomorrow -:os  ) 

The above is all that I have in the database currently... I want to create an SQL query that will replace the cat1, cat2, cat3 in table2, with the descriptions for each that are in table1...

Comment: Replace how? And "..." and "... etc" are not sample data and ">>>" is not a column. And there's no way for us to guess what you are trying to do when the output is just a pile of lists of all values. Give sample data that will suggest how the output is got from the input. (Since you seem unable to explain yourself in words.)

Comment: This looks like an awful design but if I'm understanding that part of your request, what you want to obtain can be done with `CASE`. An expression like `CASE ambro_awards_categories.cat_name WHEN 'cat1' THEN ambro_awards.cat1 WHEN 'cat2' THEN ambro_awards.cat2 etc. END` will give you the column corresponding to the given name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That design is far from optimal to say the least, but to answer your question, to the best of my knowledge you can't join tables where the name of the column of the 2nd table is the value of a column (and you certainly can't portably). However, I think that what you're after can be written this way with your current schema:

```
CREATE VIEW ambro_full_data AS
SELECT a.id as aid, c.id as cid, c.cat_name,
    CASE c.cat_name
        WHEN 'cat1' THEN a.cat1
        WHEN 'cat2' THEN a.cat2
        WHEN 'cat3' THEN a.cat3
        WHEN 'cat4' THEN a.cat4
        WHEN 'cat5' THEN a.cat5
        WHEN 'cat6' THEN a.cat6
        WHEN 'cat7' THEN a.cat7
        WHEN 'cat8' THEN a.cat8
        WHEN 'cat9' THEN a.cat9
    END as name,
    c.category,
    a.date
FROM ambro_awards_categories c
  CROSS JOIN ambro_awards a;
```

For example:

```
mysql> SELECT name FROM ambro_full_data WHERE cid = 1;
+--------------------+
| name               |
+--------------------+
| Cavey Charlesworth |
| Lynn Wylder        |
| Peter Parker       |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

or

```
mysql> SELECT category,name FROM ambro_full_data ORDER BY cid;
+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| category                                    | name               |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Would most likely know how to fondue an ant | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Would most likely know how to fondue an ant | Lynn Wylder        |
| Would most likely know how to fondue an ant | Peter Parker       |
| Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter     | Lynn Wylder        |
| Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter     | Batman             |
| Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter     | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter     | Lynn Wylder        |
| Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter     | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Most Likely to survive a nuclear winter     | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 4                                  | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Category 4                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 4                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 5                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 5                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 5                                  | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Category 6                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 6                                  | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Category 6                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 7                                  | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Category 7                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 7                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 8                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 8                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 8                                  | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Category 9                                  | Cavey Charlesworth |
| Category 9                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
| Category 9                                  | Lynn Wylder        |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when you add a column, you need to update the view correspondingly.

A better design, however, would be to have the tables like this:

`CREATE TABLE ambro_awards (id ..., voter_name ..., date ...);` (note there are no catN columns)

`CREATE TABLE ambro_awards_categories (id ..., category ...);` (note no cat_name column needed)

`CREATE TABLE ambro_awards_and_categories (a_id INTEGER NOT NULL, c_id INTEGER NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(<suitable length here>) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (a_id, c_id),
FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES ambro_awards (id), FOREIGN_KEY (c_id) REFERENCES ambro_awards_categories (id));`

With your sample data, the latter table would be like this:

```
a_id    c_id    name
1       1       Cavey Charlesworth
1       2       Cavey Charlesworth
1       3       Cavey Charlesworth
2       1       Lynn Wylder
2       2       Lynn Wylder
2       3       Lynn Wylder
3       1       Lynn Wylder
3       2       Peter Parker
3       3       Batman
```

That way you can have as many categories as you want without needing to create a column for each. Then you can do the appropriate JOINs to extract the same data as above, e.g.

`SELECT c.category, ac.name FROM ambro_awards_and_categories ac JOIN ambro_awards_categories c ON c.id = ac.c_id;`

And similar joins can be used to extract other data from the other table. For example, your original ambro_awards row 1 can be extracted to multiple rows with something like

`SELECT a.id, a.voter_name, a.date, ac.name FROM ambro_awards a JOIN ambro_awards_and_categories ac ON ac.a_id = a.id WHERE a.id = 1;`

This is pretty standard practice in SQL and should solve your problem just as well, when used adequately.

Comment: Ah, this sounds perfect. Sorry for not explaining better but you have understood what I meant.... I will go and play with the above and I`m sure all will be fine with the world.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If this is the accepted answer, would you please go ahead and accept it?